# Are there specific terms for "point up" and "point down" pentagram?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Pentagrams can have virtually any orientation but the two most common are "point up":

[image: "point up" pentagram]

And "point down":

[image: "point down" pentagram]

Is there a more appropriate term used to distinguish between these two variants?

Comment: Why *pentagrams?* Are there specific terms for *triangles* with a point or a side on top?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I happen to know that pentagrams have more symbolic weight behind them. The difference between the two carries more contextual meaning than simple triangles. But if you happen to know of a word appropriate for triangles it would probably also work for pentagrams.

Comment: I think a pentagram has to have a circle or five sided figure around the perimeter of the star.

Comment: @bib: You may be thinking of a pentacle. A pentagram is just the [connected five-pointed star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram#Classification).

Comment: @MrHen Interesting. Wiki agrees with you, but the vast majorities of images in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=pentagram&espv=210&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=9X-0UoSrBOrK2gW48oHwDA&ved=0CEwQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=642) suggest otherwise.

Comment: @bib: It's a common classification debate, actually. For the purposes of this question, I am mostly interested in the orientation.

Comment: @MrHen: Well, [this site](http://www.christian-restoration.com/fmasonry/symbols.htm) repeatedly refers to "inverted triangle". So since pentagrams (like triangles) are usually depicted "pointy-side-up", I think Shawn has probably got the right of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Point up = Pentagram

Point Down = [Inverted Pentagram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inverted%20pentagram%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: needs reference

Comment: @GEdgar: Will a couple of thousand written instances do you? I don't think it's necessary for Shawn to cite a dictionary definition of ***inverted***.